# How to get an image repeating at the top of each page in Context

Tags: graphics, header-footer, context

I can put an image on a page using `\placefigure` but how do I get an image to be placed in the header on each page, for example, a company logo?

I have looked in the manuals but can't seem to find anything, please could someone also give me a reference in the manual as well.

Comment: Have you tried putting it into the header (starer: [here](http://wiki.contextgarden.net/Headers_and_Footers))?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the choice between :

### putting the image in the header in a `framed` environnment

don't forget the right size for header (enough space for the image size)

### Creating a layer with absolute positionning of the picture

```
\useMPlibrary [dum]

\definelayer
  [logo]         %% name of the layer
  [x=5mm,        %% from upper left corner of paper
   y=5mm,
   state=repeat] %% layer appears on all pages

\setlayer
  [logo]
  {\externalfigure}

\setupbackgrounds
  [page]
  [background=logo]

\starttext
  \dorecurse{10}{\input knuth\page}
\stoptext
```

Comment: You're missing `state=repeat`, otherwise the layer will only be displayed on the current page. And what is the *sidebar* layer supposed to do?

Comment: thanks, i forgot about the `state=repeat`. i've copied my own template which contains another layer called `sidebar`. My bad. I will edit my answer . thank you again Marco